# Android MediaPlayer automatically plays the next song

Tags: android, audio, media-player

I have very basic media player code:

```
AssetFileDescriptor FileDescriptor = getAssets().openFd(musicPth);

MusicPlayer.setDataSource(FileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor());
MusicPlayer.prepare();
MusicPlayer.start();
```

For some reason when the song finishes, the player automatically plays the next song in the folder!

I've tried `setOnCompletionListener` and `setLooping` functions but it seems they don't effect the player and it just goes to the next song.

If I exclude the second mp3 then the player loops the same song which is what I want.

Very strange behavior, am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seemed to fix my problem by changing the `setDataSource()` function to this:

```
AssetFileDescriptor FileDescriptor = getAssets().openFd(musicPth);

MusicPlayer.setDataSource(FileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor(), 
    FileDescriptor.getStartOffset(), 
    FileDescriptor.getLength());

FileDescriptor.close();
```

Comment: This solved many of my problems. If you don't set offset and length, weird things will happen.